# Why does it should "" {} type check in scalatest?

Tags: scala, dsl, scalatest

How does `it should` accept a String and then a function without parenthesis :

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

class StackSpec extends FlatSpec {

  it should "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {

  }

}
```

why should it not be :

```
it(should("pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {

  }))
```

Closest I came to allowing similar to compile is :

```
object st {

  class fs {

    def it(f: => Unit) = {

    }

    def should(s: String)(f: => Unit): Unit = {
      Unit
    }

    it(should("pop values in last-in-first-out order") {

    })

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` to call functions of objects and the `()` around the parameters of functions are optional in scala. So the trick is the return objects in a chain which implement functions providing the api you want. Simple example:

```
object InObj {

  def in(func : => Unit) = func
}

object ShouldObj {

  def should(x: String) = InObj
}

trait It {

  def it = ShouldObj
}

class MyClass extends It {

  val f = it should "Do something" in {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Scala has certain rules how operators and infix method names are converted into method calls.

```
it should "foo" in {}
```

is converted into

```
it.should("foo").in({})
```

In the case where you do not use "it" but some String a implicit conversion from String to some wrapper helps to provide the should-method.